# Can I have my facilities load just once using Closest Facility when using ModelBuilder ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, closest-facility

I have tried to use Network Analyst as an extension and came across a memory issue when trying to run a Closest Facility query.

The query I want to run is routing zone origin and destinations, as facilities and incidents.  I have 2650 zones, so herein lies the memory issue as the query is routing to the network (as I'm also routing to the network, not straight line), meaning it's 2650 x 2650 routes.

I thought the best to do is to use ModelBuilder, so I could get the model to export the routes after each iteration or after a batch.  Help save on the memory.

My problem is the amount of time this is taking, I have set up a feature selection iterator so one facility is loaded at a time.  However, each time I run the model it loads in the 2650 incidents.

So my question is, can I set up ModelBuilder to not load in the locations each time?  As the loading of the locations takes about 6 hours to run.

Comment: Have you tried OD matrix tool? Sounds like your question is the book definition of OD matrix.

Comment: The OD matrix tool doesn't map the routes to the network unfortunately, which has to be done in this instance

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the number of facilities to find to greater than 2560. That way your initial run would be the 2560 origins to the 2560 destinations, instead of one at a time

Comment: The first time I ran the model, it got about 15% through the model before telling me it ran out of memory, i ran the full 2650 zones.  I've since tried to reduce the analysis and the only time I managed to successfully do this in ArcGIS (not ModelBuilder) was with 10 incidents running to the 2650 facilities.